# Overload a method with a new timeout?

Tags: c#, timeout, overloading

I am trying to overload a `static void` method with a new timeout value. Here is the code I am using:

```
public static void SetData(StringBuilder sql)
    {
        SetData(sql.ToString());
    }

    public static void SetData(string sql, int Timeout = 600)
    {

        try
        {
            OdbcConnection cnn = GetConnection();
            using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, cnn))
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            CloseConnection(cnn);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Form1.excelApp.Quit();
            MessageBox.Show("Error in SetData: " + ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Here are the references being used:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

This is my first time trying to `overload` something but my understanding is that its just passing in a value when it wasnt expecting one. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: it is overloading a method, not class.

Comment: So what problem(s) are you having with this solution?

Comment: well you are already setting a default value for the 2nd parameter

Comment: @Servy The problem I am running into is that, my understanding with timeout in c#, is that unless told otherwise the timeout is set to 30 seconds max. I am trying to execute a store procedure in my code which usually takes longer than 30 seconds. I am trying to overload a method to make it so it runs for at most 10 minutes before failing. Its still failing after 30 seconds.

Comment: @Ahmedilyas So this code is correct? I thought it was wrong due to the act it was still erroring out after 30 seconds for me.

Comment: I just noticed that `Timeout` is blue in this code, but not in my C# program. Does that mean anything, or am I indeed missing a needed Reference?

Comment: @user2405778 The coloring is different because you're using an improper naming convention, and the coloring here assumes proper naming convention.  It really should start with a lower case `t`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not just using method overloading here, you are also using the [`optional arguments`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx).

Here:

```
public static void SetData(string sql, int Timeout = 600)
```

You are giving a default value to `TimeOut` parameter.And that makes that parameter optional and that's why you can call your function with passing one parameter like this:

```
 SetData(sql.ToString());
```

The other problem is you didn't use TimeOut value inside of your function.Probably you want to set your Command's [`Timeout property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.commandtimeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, cnn))
{
     cmd.CommandTimeout = TimeOut;
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Also it would be better it you define your `OdbcConnection` inside of `using` statement which will `Dispose` your connection automatically:

```
using (OdbcConnection cnn = GetConnection())
using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, cnn))
{
    cmd.CommandTimeout = TimeOut;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    CloseConnection(cnn);
}
```

Comment: He is actually overloading the method as well, in addition to using optional parameters.

Comment: How I have it now, should this properly change the default `Timeout` to 10 minutes? Also thanks for linking me to the description of optional arguments.

Comment: @user2405778 you didn't use that timeout value inside of your function anywhere

Comment: @Selman22 That...that would be a good reason as to why its not working.

Comment: @user2405778 see my update,and yes and if you set timeout to 600 then it will set the default timeout to 10 minutes according to documentation

Answer (score 1):

Your method accepts a timeout parameter, but then you proceed to ignore that timeout value and never actually pass it along to your query.  It cannot magically know that you intend this value to be used as the timeout.  You need to set the timeout value of the command to the value in that parameter.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my silly mistake and your comments explaining other items.